# Cant connect to database from springboot app: password authentication failed for user "user"

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to connect spring boot app to the postgres on docker but I got org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user"
even if I use correct password(I belive so)

docker-compose.yml in main project dir:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

application.yml in springboot app dir:

```
 server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: customer
  datasource:
    password: password
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/customer
    username: user
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
```

pg_hba.conf in docker:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Steps I've taken to create database:

Docker compose up -d

[starting containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ3Nk.jpg)

[go to http://localhost:5050/browser/# and enter master password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LvxT.jpg)

[creating server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCTIH.jpg)

[creating database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO01A.jpg)

and when I try to run spring boot app I got

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user"

I tried to restart images and delete them. Please help to find the bug in my configuration.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: yes, I have changed ports on postgres container "51:5432"

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following to you *docker-compose.yml*, it will probably work.

```
 POSTGRES_DB: customer
```

You did no create the "schema", and that's why you are getting the error.

The postgres image configuration with the fix:

```
postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: customer
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: Unfortunately still the same. This time postgres created schema but I got the same exception when I run springboot app. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you access the postgres with the same credentials in another client? For example using IntelliJ Database connector, or other client? Also, almost sure is not it, but can you remove the port from the connection string? "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/customer". Another try you can do is not using the volume this time to see if something changes. Maybe you volume as already something that does not allow the connection.

Comment: nothing changed. Do you think that can be caused by blocked ports on my work laptop?